# Is this possible to get notification for all emails that arrive on an Android phone?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, jakarta-mail

Is this possible to somehow get notified whenever an email, for any email address, arrives on an Android phone (whether this account is using the default email application or any other email client)?

I am using the Java mail API.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you'll have to define a `BroadcastReceiver` listening for incoming emails.
Now, you should focus your investigation on discovering what `Intent` is fired when a new email arrives.

Note that this may be specific per application, and other mail clients may not send any Intents at all.